Can I output thumbnails instead full images on a webform email confirmation?
I have a form where people can upload images for approval.  A confirmation email goes out saying thank you etc with an output of what they have uploaded using this token:
[webform_submission:values:my_photo]

This all works fine, except that the image/s shown on the email are full size. I know how to change the format on the View that is used to review these images, but is there a way to do this on the email sent out on the Webform submission? I want to show a thumbnail or scaled down version of the image to make the email more readable.
